# Regexp to match random order words

Tags: python, regex

I have the following pseudo-DSL:

```
< allow | deny > 
< tcp | udp | any >  
src < prefix | $ip | @hostgroup | any > [ port number | range | @portgroup | any ] 
dst < prefix | $ip | @hostgroup | any > [ port number | range | @portgroup | any ] 
[ stateful ] 
[ expire YYYYMMDD ] [ log ] 
[ # comment ]
```

The order is fixed, starting from allow up to `dst` and its `port`.
That I'm matching with the following, rather dumb, regexp:

```
m = re.search("^(allow|deny)?\s+(tcp|udp|tcpudp|any)\s+?(src\s\S+)\s*?(port\s+\S+)?\s*?(dst\s\S+)\s?(port\s+\S+)?\s*?(\S+)?\s*?(\S+)?", line)
```

Pardon me for the n00bness of the questions, but the parts I'm having problems with are:

1. How can I match `stateful`, `expire <value>`, `log` if all 3 are optional but in case they are present I want to match them in separate groups.
2. How can I match optional statement `port <value>` in such a way that the match group will contain only the value, without creating an extra matching group, i.e. without using `(port\s+(\S+))?`

Thanks!

[edit for more of a problem statement]

To elaborate a bit more, sure I can check whether one of the 3 groups contain either `log` or `stateful`, but if I use the same approach, a non-capturing group for expire, aka `(?:expire\s(\S+))`, I'd need to make an assumption. Unless I can somehow have order-less matching? i.e. match on `(stateful|log|(?:expire\s(\S+)))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How can I match `stateful`, `expire <value>`, `log` if all 3 are optional but in case they are present I want to match them in separate groups.

Use capture groups that have a `?` after them so that they will be optional.

Ex. `\s*(stateful)?\s*(?:expire (\d{8}))?\s*(log)?`

To allow those optional groups to appear in any order in the match string, but still always have them in the same numbered capture group, use a look-ahead `(?= )`.

Ex. `(?=(?:.*(stateful))?)(?=(?:.*expire (\d{8}))?)(?=(?:.*(log))?)`

> 2. How can I match optional statement `port <value>` in such a way that the match group will contain only the value, without creating an extra matching group, i.e. without using
>      `(port\s+(\S+))?`

Use a non-capturing group `(?: )` to put those characters together for the following `?` without capturing them. (You probably want to do this for `expire` above also)

```
(?:port\s+(\s+))?
```

### [Complete Regex](https://regex101.com/r/tV6oB3/4)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the non-capturing group hint, haven't thought of that. Regarding the optional groups.. I guess what I'm after is that regardless of the order of those 3 - it would be nice if matched group index would remain the same. But now I'm asking too much, am I? :)

Comment: You could use a look-ahead that contains a capture group. Then the optional statements can be in any order, and the capture groups will always have the same index. Would you like me to explain in the answer?

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, sure I can check whether one of the 3 groups contain either `log` or `stateful`, but if I use the same approach, a non-capturing group for `expire`, aka `(?:expire\s(\S+))`, I'd need to make an assumption. Unless I can somehow have order-less matching? i.e. match on `(stateful|log|(?:expire\s(\S+)))`?

Comment: would love to hear about the lookahead. Read about it, but can't seem to wrap my head around just yet - if you could help me understand on this example - would be wonderful!

Comment: Yeah! There's an edit now with an example of that. Does that help?

Comment: Hmm. Makes sense, however...  http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(allow%7Cdeny)%3F%5Cs%2B(tcp%7Cudp%7Ctcpudp%7Cany)%5Cs%2B%3F(src%5Cs%5CS%2B)%5Cs*(%3F%3Aport%5Cs%2B(%5CS%2B))%3F%5Cs*(dst%5Cs%5CS%2B)%5Cs%3F(%3F%3Aport%5Cs%2B(%5CS%2B))%3F(%3F%3D%5Cs*(stateful)%3F)(%3F%3D%5Cs*(expire%20%5Cd%7B8%7D)%3F)(%3F%3D%5Cs*(log)%3F)&test_string=allow%20tcp%20src%2010.34.236.0%2F27%20port%20any%20dst%2010.32.160.80%20port%20%40web_services%20stateful%20log&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: In fact, it catches only the first word, following the non-look-ahead patterns.

Comment: Hah! I was experimenting as well, but didn't figure it out. Awesome man, you're a lifesaver, thank you! Uhh, was about to say I understand, but coming to think of it - what does a non-capturing `(?:.*(term))?` add there? I've read that an optional look-ahead doesn't make sense, but...

Comment: I've created [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449492/matching-optional-capture-groups-in-any-order/37449493#37449493) in hopes of getting other people involved in solving that particular issue. There likely are other, better ways of doing it.